# jQuery - Add CSS class only on Safari on iOS7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, browser-detection

I want to add the class "ios7-fix" only for Safari on iOS7.

I have coded that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match('Safari')) { $('body').addClass('ios7-fix'); }
}
```

But: It adding the class "ios7-fix" to chrome on iOS7 too. Why?

Du you have a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Chrome has both 'Chrome' and 'Safari' inside userAgent string.
Safari has only 'Safari'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried the solution in the link - it didn't worked for me. :/